# Error when splitting string into two variables in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to be able to input a users full name in an entry box and then have it split into a firstname and surname variable, so that these variables can be used to search a database for. However, I'm having issues with this, as it is something I haven't really done before. Any help is appreciated.

```
    studentname = (StudName.get())
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    firstName, lastName = studentname.split()
    namesearchadd = (firstname, lastname,)
    c.execute ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE FName = ? and SName= ? VALUES (?,?);", (namesearchadd,))
    data = c.fetchall()
    if len(data) == 0:
        print ("whoops")
    else:
        Label(screen6, text = "Success", fg="GREEN").place(relx=0.101, rely=0.725, height=21, width=194) 

firstName, lastName = studentname.split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Comment: In your code you expected 2 values:
'firstName' and 'lastName', but the value of `studentname` is empty that is the reason you get 0.

Comment: That sql isn't giving a syntax error? Plus even if it's somehow accepted it has 4 placeholders and you're passing 2 values...